# MVC List ViewModel not Binding upon form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a **viewModel**, which has a property of type `List<chartPopup_ViewModel>`, this property is always NULL upon form submission.

My ViewModels

```
namespace FrontEnd.ViewModels
{
    public class chartPopup_ViewModel
    {
        public string columnID { get; set; }
        public string rowID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Md.Dal.entities.lookup_chart_values> lookup_chart_values { get; set; }

        public int index { get; set; }

    }

    public class chartPopupHeader_ViewModel
    {



        public int chartID { get; set; }
        public List<chartPopup_ViewModel> chartValues; --<--null upon form post

    }
}
```

And my View...

```
@model FrontEnd.ViewModels.chartPopupHeader_ViewModel
    @Html.TextBox("chartID", 222)

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.chartValues.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.chartValues[i].columnID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.chartValues[i].index)
    }
```

my controller...

```
    public string SaveChart(chartPopupHeader_ViewModel vm)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

**chartValues** is NULL when I submit the form. why is chartValues not binding... chartValues is a type `List<chartPopup_ViewModel>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a [`property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), not a [`field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx):

```
public List<chartPopup_ViewModel> chartValues { get; set; }
```

Comment: my GOD. spent 2 hours and totally ignored the fact that its NOT a property.

Comment: No problem, that's why an additional pair of eyes helps sometimes :-)